# Rename Iterm2 tab from within tmux

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

I can use the following function to rename a iterm2 tab and that works great.

```
function rename_tab {
    echo -ne "\033]0;"$@"\007"
}
```

However, if I run this function while in a tmux session, then nothing happens.

Any idea how to make this work while in tmux?  Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the tmux option `set-titles`

In my .tmux.conf I have the following line:

`set-option -g set-titles on`

You will need to restart the tmux server (kill existing sessions) or re-source the file before the change in your config takes effect. You can also run this for an existing session with `<prefix>:set-option set-titles on`

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks! <prefix>:set-option set-titles-string tab-name-here did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: set-option -g set-titles on
set-option -g set-titles-string '#S'

Comment: You can reload the tmux config pretty easily with `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`. Source - http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/reloading-tmux-config/

Comment: This does not work when using the tmux integration (e.g. running with tmux -CC )

Comment: Any solution for using control mode (aka `tmux -CC`)? May be a bug in tmux?

Answer (score 5):

I could not get the set-titles to work when using the tmux integration in iTerm2 (running with `tmux -CC`)

Instead this works just fine

```
function tabname {
  if [ -z $TMUX ] ; then
    printf "\e]1;$@\a"
  else
   tmux rename-window "$@"
  fi
}
```

Comment: Did you put this in your .bashrc/.zshrc file? Or could we place this into .tmux.conf?

Comment: I put it in `.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not a direct reply to the question, sorry about that. It is instead how to do this from iTerm2 without a command line equivalent.

iTerm Menu Bar -> Shell ->

[image: Shell]

tmux ->

[image: tmux]

Dashboard -> select a window ->

[image: Dashboard]

Press return to rename (just like in Finder!)
[image: Press enter to rename]